# New Record creation on custom object - An internal server error has occurred - Error ID: 1803087759-275934 (-1232085095)

Tags: custom-object, dml, gack

I am trying to create a new record on a custom object which has record types and save the record. I get the below error

> An internal server error has occurred An error has occurred while
>   processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been
>   notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional
>   information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the
>   error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of
>   the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well
>   as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using
>   salesforce.com!
>
> Error ID: 1803087759-275934 (-1232085095)
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Any help would be appreciated. 
We have also created a ticket with salesforce.

Comment: I will post the answer if i get inputs from salesforce support. It could help others in the future

Comment: Can you paste your code for which you are getting this error.

Comment: No code just new record creation from ui.  No trigger as well on the object

Comment: Lightning or Classic? One record type or all record types? Does it matter what data you input? Are all required fields populated? The devil's in the details.

Comment: in Both. All record types.Entered all Required fields. agree on devil is in the detail part :). weird thing is now its all working fine. we are waiting for official response from salesforce support. Issue is intermittent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if it helps others, Answer from salesforce support

R&D and Tier 3 have provided a root cause analysis:

A single organization's storage might be spread across multiple tables for load balancing. Because we're a shared hosting service, those individual tables will also contain data from other organizations. This means that each of your individual objects might be saved to different tables, and those tables might contain data from multiple organizations.

The storage for the table that Generic_Log__c was reaching had exceeded its storage, resulting in the error you encountered.

There is an automated job in place that monitors for space usage and adds storage once it has reached a certain threshold. In this case, a bug was encountered that prevented this automated increase from happening.

Since the storage exists and the job processes at a table level on the instance and not an individual organization level:

- Multiple orgs might have been impacted if they attempted to save data to the impacted table.
- A single org might be impacted on one object that saved data to the impacted table, but not on another object if it saved data to a different table.
- A single org might not have been impacted at all if that org did not save data to the impacted table.

A bug was created to address the issue with the automated job. R&D has identified a fix for the bug, and we're waiting for confirmation on whether it is still pending deployment or has been deployed already.

There was an additional question provided about why did the record save process work for a time. It's hard to say at this time, but it's likely that the storage was teetering on the "exceeded" limit at that time, and data was deleted in some way (example, sandbox refresh) that temporarily brought the storage below the limit.